# what is the best way to find out if a value is already in the database using jpa

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa

i have this method in my service that registers a new staff member:

```
public String addStaffMember(Staff staffMember){
   if (!userRepository.existsById(staffMember.getId())){
       if (!userRepository.existsByPhone(staffMember.getUser().getPhone())){
           if (!userRepository.existsByEmail(staffMember.getUser().getEmail())){
               staffRepository.save(staffMember);
               return "Staff member registered";
           }else {
               throw  new StaffMemberAlreadyExistsException("This email already exists");
           }
       }else {
           throw  new StaffMemberAlreadyExistsException("this phone already exists");
       }
   }else
   {
       throw new StaffMemberAlreadyExistsException("This user already exists");
   }

}
```

It seems to me that this is poor code and has poor readability. Is there a better way to write this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following method to your repository that checks all the constraints you have listed:

```
boolean existsByIdOrPhoneOrEmail(Long id, String phone, String email)
```

This assumes your id is a Long. See [this page](https://www.javaguides.net/2023/08/spring-data-jpa-existsby-multiple.html) for additional 'exists' examples.

Comment: i did do it like that at first but there is no way to  make a custom message to specify what exactly exists.

Comment: If you want to efficiently check for uniqueness you would have to have an error message that states something like 'Staff member already exists, or phone or email must be unique ...' otherwise you have to know which constraint caused the violation which mean separate queries.